# How to restrict access to a part of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to use only specific part of the base class, while hiding other parts. Consider the following code:

```
struct IX
{
    // ...
};

struct IY
{
    // ...
};

class Base :
    public IX,
    public IY
{
    // Implements IX and IY.
    // ...
};


// Reuse IX implementation, but don't expose IY.
//
class X : protected Base
{
public:
    using Base::IX; // <-- Doesn't exist in C++.
};
```

Can I enjoy the `IX` implementation provided by `Base`, but without exposing `IY` interface?

Of course, I could type `using Base::IX::xxx` for all methods, which exist in `IX`. Alternatively, I could forward all calls to implementation like this:

```
//
class X : public IX
{
public:
    // Forward all calls to IX methods to m_p.
    // ...

protected:
    Base* m_p;
};
```

But again, I have to type all methods available in `IX` in order to forward them. And every time `IX` changes, I'll have to update `X`.

Thanks.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Well basically implementation of `IX` and `IY` is protected in your `class X`. You can expose accessors and modifiers as public methods inside your class.

Another approach would be to expose publicly IX from Base:

```
class Base : public IX, protected IY
{
    // Implements IX and IY.
    // ...
    // Expose access to IY through base for the class 
    // inheriting from Base
};

class X : public Base
```

Another possibility is not to inherit from `IX` and `IY` but to keep them as public members of your `Base`:

```
class Base
{
public:
    IX member1;
    IY member2;
};
```

This way you can inherit protectedly from Base and can expose a single accessor and modifier method from your `class X` for `member1`.

Comment: @konstantin-d-infragistics `IX` and `Base` already exist and used in other places. Also, `IX` contains quite a lot of things like `typedef`'s, nested classes, etc. So, modifying `X` every time when `IX` changes can be a daunting task.

Comment: @AlexBlekhman I have made and edit and there are two suggestions. The first one still assumes that you would have to change Base if you change IY. The second one does not require changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, in order to use the second variant I'll have to implement `IX` and `IY` first. So, `Base` will have members like `IXImpl` and `IYImpl`. It makes usage of `Base` for other users quite cumbersome. I tend to think that the problem doesn't have clean solution in C++. So, inheriting from `IX` and forwarding all calls internally probably is the least dirty way to solve it.